# Is it posible to create a log.info pointcut?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I never tried AOP before and want to know if I could make a pointcut that captures the execution of a log.info(...) in Spring.

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class AfterFinallyExample  {

    @After("execution(* org.slf4j.*.*(..))")
    public void sendLogParameterToServer() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If it is posible, is it consider a good practice?

Comment: What do you mean by, is it a good practice? Also your question should focus on the problem. What are you trying to achieve by such an aspect?

Comment: Hi, I just want to execute some logic after a simple "log.info(...)" is executed, in every log.info (or .trace, .debug, etc) in my project. I have seen a lot of examples of capturing public methos, but not capturing library methods like org.slf4j.log, that´s why I´m asking if it is a good practice.

Comment: No you cannot with plain Spring AOP. As that operates only on Spring Managed beans and not other types of objects. A logger isn't spring managed so it won't work. If you really want this you will need to resort to full-blown aspectj with either compile or loadtime weaving. Also what do you want to execute after logging? You might be better of writing your own appended instead.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, this is the kind of limitation I was thinking of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use AOP to do this, yes you could. Can you do it with, the default, Spring AOP no you cannot.

Spring AOP, by default, is based on proxies and it will only create proxies for Spring-managed beans. As the loggers aren't managed by Spring (unless you inject all loggers) this won't work.

You will need to resort to fullblown AspectJ with either compile or loadtime weaving. Which will change the actual bytecode of the classes based on the pointcut and aspect.